# Can I integrate the Android billing services into an app made with MonoDroid?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin, android-billing

Currently debating on using Xamarin for a project, anybody got any ideas on android billing system? ideally on the subscription service. Is it all done through play store?

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with Xamarin and MonoDroid. Also, FYI, they bumped up the price recently from $399 to $999 per SDK -- unless your app compiles to under 32kb of CIL (good luck with *that* requirement ...)

Comment: Looks like it's still $299 on the website: https://store.xamarin.com/

Comment: its 299 for individuals. On the android dev site there is code samples for billing info where as on xamarins site i couldnt find any, this is what im getting at.

Answer (score 1):

[In-app billing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html) requires sending requests from your app to `IInAppBillingService`. This requires using an AIDL file to invoke IPC method calls, but it is currently [not supported](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/services/part_2_-_bound_services#Inter-process_Communication_with_Services) by Mono for Android. However, it is still possible use AIDL in Mono for Android, but need some workarounds. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7876830/620138).

Also, I heard there are some existing solutions to do in-app billing, check [this](https://github.com/MarkEaton1/Monodroid-InApp-Billing) or [this](https://github.com/jmawebtech/MonoGame-StarterKits/tree/master/Android/InAppBilling).